# monte carlo simulation in python: parallelization using ipyparallel taking longer time than serialization

Tags: python, serialization, parallel-processing, montecarlo

hei,

I am making monte carlo simulation of photon transport in scattering media. I am trying to paralelize it but have difficulties in observing any performances improvement in running time compare to a serial simulation

The montecarlo code can be found below. The class Photon contains various methods for computing transport and scattering of single photon, while the class RunPhotonPackage run a series, N, of photons for a given thickness, L, of scattering media. Those are for the moment my only input parameters:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random as rand


NPHOTONS = 100000 # Nb photons
PI  = np.pi
EPS = 1.e-6
L = 100. # scattering layer thickness

class Photon():

    mut = 0.02 
    k = [0,0,1]

    def __init__(self,ko,pos):
        Photon.k = ko
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.z = pos[2]

    def move(self):
        ksi = rand(1)
        s = -np.log(1-ksi)/Photon.mut

        self.x = self.x + s*Photon.k[0]
        self.y = self.y + s*Photon.k[1]
        self.z = self.z + s*Photon.k[2]       
        zPos = self.z
        return zPos 

    def exittop(self):

        newZpos = 0


    def exitbase(self):
        newZpos = 0


    def HG(self,g):
        rand_teta = rand(1)
        costeta = 0.5*(1+g**2-((1-g**2)/(1-g + 2.*g*rand_teta))**2)/g

        return costeta

    def scatter(self):
        # calculate new angle of scattering
        phi = 2*PI*rand(1)                
        costeta = self.HG(0.85)
        sinteta = (1-costeta**2)**0.5 


        sinphi = np.sin(phi) 
        cosphi = np.cos(phi)

        temp = (1-Photon.k[2]**2)**0.5

        if np.abs(temp) > EPS:        

            mux = sinteta*(Photon.k[0]*Photon.k[2]*cosphi-Photon.k[1]*sinphi)/temp + Photon.k[0]*costeta 
            muy = sinteta*(Photon.k[1]*Photon.k[2]*cosphi+Photon.k[0]*sinphi)/temp + Photon.k[1]*costeta
            muz = -sinteta*cosphi*temp + Photon.k[2]*costeta

        else:
            mux = sinteta*cosphi 
            muy = sinteta*sinphi
            if Photon.k[2]>=0:
                muz = costeta
            else:
                muz = -costeta


        # update the new direction of the photon 
        Photon.k[0] = mux
        Photon.k[1] = muy
        Photon.k[2] = muz        


class RunPhotonPackage():

    def __init__(self,L,NPHOTONS):
        self.L = L
        self.NPHOTONS = NPHOTONS

    def RunPhoton(self):
        Dist_Pos = np.zeros((3,self.NPHOTONS))
        # loop over number of photon
        for i in range(self.NPHOTONS):

            # inititate initial photon direction
            k_init = [0,0,1]
            k_init_norm = k_init/np.linalg.norm(k_init) # initial photon direction.
            # initiate new photon with initial direction   
            pos_init = [0,0,0]
            newPhoton = Photon(k_init_norm,pos_init)
            newZpos = 0.

            # while the photon is still in the layer, move it and scatter it
            while ((newZpos >= 0.) and (newZpos <= self.L)):

                newZpos = newPhoton.move()
                newscatter = newPhoton.scatter()

            Dist_Pos[0,i] = newPhoton.x
            Dist_Pos[1,i] = newPhoton.y
            Dist_Pos[2,i] = newPhoton.z


        return Dist_Pos
```

I run the following serial code to record a position histogram for various layer thickness length and a given number of photon.

```
import time
tic = time.time()
dictresult = {}
for L in np.arange(10,100,10):
    print('L={0} m'.format(L))
    Dist_Pos = RunPhotonPackage(L,10000).RunPhoton()
    dictresult['{0}'.format(L)]=Dist_Pos
toc = time.time()
print('sec Elapsed: {0}s'.format(toc-tic))
```

then this run in:

```
sec Elapsed: 26.425330162s
```

When I try to parallelize the code using ipyparallel:

```
import ipyparallel
clients = ipyparallel.Client()
clients.ids
dview = clients[:]

dview.execute('import numpy as np')
dview.execute('from numpy.random import random as rand')
dview['PI'] = np.pi
dview['EPS']= 1.e-6

dview.push({"Photon": Photon, "RunPhotonPackage": RunPhotonPackage})

def RunPhotonPara(L):
    LayerL = RunPhotonPackage(L,10000)
    dPos = LayerL.RunPhoton()
    return dPos

tic = time.time()
dictresultpara = []
for L in np.arange(10,100,10):
    print('L={0}'.format(L))
    value = dview.apply_async(RunPhotonPara,L)
    dictresultpara.append(value)
    clients.wait(dictresultpara)
toc = time.time()
print('sec Elapsed: {0}s'.format(toc-tic))
```

it runs in:

```
sec Elapsed: 55.4289810658s
```

So more than double the time!!! I am running this on ubuntu 32 bits with four cores and start one controller and 4 engines on localhost using `ipcluster start -n 4`. I was expecting that the paralelized code would run in ~1/4 the time taken to run the serial one but obviously it does not.

Why is that and how to correct for it?

Thanks for any advices.

Greg

Comment: This is `embarrassingly parallel`, so it should be rather simple. Ran it, 13 secs for single machine, 0.63 secs for 4 cores, doesn't make sense either. (Win10, Anaconda install)

Comment: That´s what I was thinking. I ran it on windows 7, anaconda install, 8 cores and got 18 s for serial simulation and 28 for paralell 8 cores. There was an error when defining the  RunPhotonPackage as:  class RunPhotonPackage(object). Removing object make the code run. I edited and corrected my question.

Comment: Hm, Still serial 12 secs, parallel on 4 cores 0.3-0.5 secs, i.e. too fast. But I didn't actually read your code or look at the outputs.

Comment: There was an error in the output when running the first script. It should run ok now.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting 12secs for single and ~13 secs for parallel run, that would make sense now.

Comment: then I do not understand how you manage to get so close results in running time between serial and paralell and what I am doing wrong? Have you changed something in the code? On windows 7 I am using Ipython notebook and starts 8 cores using the IPython clusters tab extension in my Notebook.

Comment: No. No changes, I just ran your updated code (win10, i7, 16GB ram, don't remember the processor settings at bootup, but check yours).  I get 4 results (running 4 cores) in roughly the same time as a single result (some penalty for overhead) which is what your intent was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to simplify your example. The serial version runs in ~18 sec on my Mac, and the parallel version with 4 engines runs in about half the time. This seems reasonable given the uneven duration of the tasks.

The way it was previously set up, errors were occurring in the engines, thus the fast returns. It appears that passing classes via the dictionary is not adequate. Instead, the code now imports the module defining the classes on each engine. **Note that I simply hacked sys.path for this example**, but presumably in a production environment you'd handle this appropriately.

I don't think you want a "wait" inside the loop. Also, the async_map() method seemed more convenient than async_apply().

To run this, create a directory, copy the following code into a file called "photon.py" in that directory, and create an empty "**init**.py" there as well. Modify the line in the code that inserts into sys.path to refer to your new directory. Change directory there and run "python photon.py":

```
# photon.py

import ipyparallel
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random as rand
import time

NPHOTONS = 100000 # Nb photons
PI  = np.pi
EPS = 1.e-6
L = 100. # scattering layer thickness

class Photon():

    mut = 0.02 
    k = [0,0,1]

    def __init__(self,ko,pos):
        Photon.k = ko
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.z = pos[2]

    def move(self):
        ksi = rand(1)
        s = -np.log(1-ksi)/Photon.mut

        self.x = self.x + s*Photon.k[0]
        self.y = self.y + s*Photon.k[1]
        self.z = self.z + s*Photon.k[2]       
        zPos = self.z
        return zPos 

    def exittop(self):

        newZpos = 0


    def exitbase(self):
        newZpos = 0


    def HG(self,g):
        rand_teta = rand(1)
        costeta = 0.5*(1+g**2-((1-g**2)/(1-g + 2.*g*rand_teta))**2)/g

        return costeta

    def scatter(self):
        # calculate new angle of scattering
        phi = 2*PI*rand(1)                
        costeta = self.HG(0.85)
        sinteta = (1-costeta**2)**0.5 


        sinphi = np.sin(phi) 
        cosphi = np.cos(phi)

        temp = (1-Photon.k[2]**2)**0.5

        if np.abs(temp) > EPS:        

            mux = sinteta*(Photon.k[0]*Photon.k[2]*cosphi-Photon.k[1]*sinphi)/temp + Photon.k[0]*costeta 
            muy = sinteta*(Photon.k[1]*Photon.k[2]*cosphi+Photon.k[0]*sinphi)/temp + Photon.k[1]*costeta
            muz = -sinteta*cosphi*temp + Photon.k[2]*costeta

        else:
            mux = sinteta*cosphi 
            muy = sinteta*sinphi
            if Photon.k[2]>=0:
                muz = costeta
            else:
                muz = -costeta


        # update the new direction of the photon 
        Photon.k[0] = mux
        Photon.k[1] = muy
        Photon.k[2] = muz        


class RunPhotonPackage():

    def __init__(self,L,NPHOTONS):
        self.L = L
        self.NPHOTONS = NPHOTONS

    def RunPhoton(self):
        Dist_Pos = np.zeros((3,self.NPHOTONS))
        # loop over number of photon
        for i in range(self.NPHOTONS):

            # inititate initial photon direction
            k_init = [0,0,1]
            k_init_norm = k_init/np.linalg.norm(k_init) # initial photon direction.
            # initiate new photon with initial direction   
            pos_init = [0,0,0]
            newPhoton = Photon(k_init_norm,pos_init)
            newZpos = 0.

            # while the photon is still in the layer, move it and scatter it
            while ((newZpos >= 0.) and (newZpos <= self.L)):

                newZpos = newPhoton.move()
                newscatter = newPhoton.scatter()

            Dist_Pos[0,i] = newPhoton.x
            Dist_Pos[1,i] = newPhoton.y
            Dist_Pos[2,i] = newPhoton.z

        return Dist_Pos

def RunPhoton(L):
    print('L={0}'.format(L))
    return RunPhotonPackage(L, 10000).RunPhoton()

def serialTest(values):
    print "Running serially..."
    tic = time.time()
    results = map(RunPhoton, values)
    print results
    toc = time.time()
    print('sec Elapsed: {0}s'.format(toc-tic))

def parallelTest(values):
    print "Running in parallel..."
    client = ipyparallel.Client()
    view = client[:]

    view.execute('import sys')

    # CHANGE THIS PATH TO REFER TO WHEREVER YOU PUT THIS CODE
    view.execute('sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/rjp/ipp")')
    view.execute('from photon import *')

    tic = time.time()
    asyncResults = view.map_async(RunPhoton, values)
    print asyncResults.get()
    toc = time.time()
    print('sec Elapsed: {0}s'.format(toc-tic))    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    values = np.arange(10, 100, 10)

    serialTest(values)
    parallelTest(values)
```

Comment: hei, that works perfectly! I got also a parallel version running ~two time faster than the serial one.  thanks.

Comment: Hei Rich, maybe an additional short question? While the solution you gave work perfectly running "python photon.py" in a terminal, it fails when trying to run parallelTest(values) in spyder (serialTest(values) works fine however). In spyder, the asyncResults.get() command never return anything and the program seems to hang up. Why?